# JS Show/Hide DIV Toggler Snaps To Top Of Page

Tags: jquery, toggle, href, show-hide

I'm using a Java Script Show/Hide DIV Toggler I found [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/#comment-179741). It works, but with the side effect that each click on the  toggle takes me to the top of the page. Checked in FF and Chrome, same deal in both browsers. I can't tell for sure if it's restarting the page but I know it's not reloading it.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

This is the toggle (notice the href="#" - is that the problem?):

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('gallery_info');">[Click to see more details]</a>
```

And this is the div being shown/hidden (as you can see it starts hidden):

```
<div id="gallery_info" style="display: none;">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use javascript: as href instead of #

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="toggle_visibility('gallery_info');">[Click to see more details]</a>
```

Comment: Or `javascript:void(0)` : The operator `void` will return a null value so the browser will not load a new page.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for that, I've used javascript:void(0) and it works a treat! Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

that's not related to the function, it's the `a` tag which jumps to the top of the page, you can use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` within the function for preventing the `a` tag's default action.

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.preventDefault()` to the function to stop the default behavior of clicking the link. Specifying `href='#'` indicates a link to the top of the current page, which is why you are currently seeing that behavior. If you are using jquery you can also `return false` from the function instead.

Note that the variable `e` above is the event object passed as the first argument to the onclick function

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear, I meant the `e` referenced in my answer, not the one that he has in his function. I was worried he would get confused since he had already defined a variable named `e`

Comment: I'd be happy to see how you would implement `e.preventDefault()`   http://jsbin.com/ilisoj/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't get it to work for some reason (I think my lack of skill and understanding is the culprit :D ) but found the above works well for me. Appreciate it!